# SQL subquery how to get the details of the maximum item for each group

Tags: mysql, sql

Using this query I can produce the following results:

```
SELECT product_group_id, product_id, product_price, product_description
    FROM product_group_table
    JOIN product ON product.id = product_id;
```

| product_group_id | product_id | product_price | product_description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 | 15 | Loremipsum 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 10 | Loremipsum 2 |
| 5 | 3 | 24 | Loremipsum 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 30 | Loremipsum 4 |

The output I want is the following:

| product_group_id | product_id | product_price | product_description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 4 | 30 | Loremipsum 4 |
| 5 | 3 | 24 | Loremipsum 3 |

Where I get the details of the product with the highest price per group.
I tried it with the query:

```
SELECT product_group_id, product_id, MAX(product_price) AS product_price, product_description
FROM (SELECT product_group_id, product_id, product_price, product_description
    FROM product_group_table
    JOIN product ON product.id = product_id) 
    AS product_group_table
    GROUP BY product_group_id;
```

But it produces the following result.

| product_group_id | product_id | product_price | product_description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 | 30 | Loremipsum 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 24 | Loremipsum 3 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One other method to achieve this is by using `SUB-QUERY` and `JOINS`. This method will work with most of the oldest versions of `MySQL` as well:

```
SELECT pg.product_group_id, pg.product_id, pg.product_price, pg.product_description
FROM 
(
    SELECT product_group_id, product_id, product_price, product_description
    FROM product_group_table
    JOIN product ON product.id = product_id
)AS pg
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT product_group_id, MAX(product_price) AS mx_price
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT product_group_id, product_id, product_price, product_description
    FROM product_group_table
    JOIN product ON product.id = product_id
  ) sq
  GROUP BY product_group_id
) AS mx
    ON pg.product_group_id = mx.product_group_id
    AND pg.product_price = mx.mx_price
ORDER BY pg.product_group_id;
```

Demo on *db<>fiddle* [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=2855e1f536d006e80f542668759213be)

Answer (score 0):

One canonical approach, assuming you use MySQL 8+, uses `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pgt.product_group_id
                                 ORDER BY p.product_price DESC) rn
    FROM product_group_table pgt
    INNER JOIN product p ON pgt.product_id = p.id
)

SELECT product_group_id, product_id, product_price, product_description
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Remark (OP must understand this if he needs in deterministic output). If there exists more than one row with the same maximal `product_price` value than indefinite one of them will be selected. If OP needs to return some definite row which is defined by some additional criteria (for example, maximal `product_id`) then he must expand `ORDER BY` expression in window definition accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am using MySql Version 5. This problem can be solved by casting from one datatype to another. The query is as follows. It is working. I am assuming that the table name is PRODUCT.

```
SELECT      A.PRODUCT_GROUP_ID,A.PRODUCT_ID,A.PRODUCT_PRICE,A.PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION
FROM        PRODUCT A
WHERE       CONCAT(TRIM(CAST(A.PRODUCT_GROUP_ID AS CHAR(10))),'-',TRIM(CAST(A.PRODUCT_PRICE AS CHAR(10)))) IN
(
        SELECT      CONCAT(TRIM(CAST(B.PRODUCT_GROUP_ID AS CHAR(10))),'-',TRIM(CAST(MAX(B.PRODUCT_PRICE) AS CHAR(10)))) 
        FROM        PRODUCT B
        GROUP BY    B.PRODUCT_GROUP_ID
)
ORDER BY    A.PRODUCT_GROUP_ID,A.PRODUCT_ID;
```